# cx_freeze and VPython giving a syntax error

Tags: python, compression, exe, cx-freeze, vpython

I'm trying to compress my VPython code to a .exe, but it comes up with a syntax error:

[image]

this is the only screenshot I have of it right now, I'm away from my home pc.

I know that the setup.py file works because I did it with a program that doesn't use VPython modules and it works fine.

Anyone else had a problem with cx_freeze and VPython? Any alternatives or recommendations?

I'm on python 3.2.2, with VPython version 5.74.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use argument unpacking on Python 3.

The syntax used to work in Python 2 but was removed from Python 3 (see [PEP 3113](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3113/) for the arguments):

```
Python 2.7.5 (default, May 22 2013, 12:00:45) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Based on Apple Inc. build 5658) (LLVM build 2336.11.00)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> lambda ((left, right), value): None
<function <lambda> at 0x10d3f1488>
```

vs.

```
Python 3.3.2 (default, May 22 2013, 12:04:15) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 4.2 (clang-425.0.28)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> lambda ((left, right), value): None
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    lambda ((left, right), value): None
           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Use *one* argument for the `((left, right), value)` structure, and address the components in the `lambda`. Or better still, use a function and unpack the structure in the function body.

Comment: So I expect my problem is with cx_freeze? I didn't write any of the code apart from the setup.py file, and when I didn't use VPython it worked, so surely it's not a problem with how I'm compressing it, but _what_ I'm compressing?

Comment: No, your problem is with Python 3. If cx_freeze uses Python 3 instead of Python 2 to run your code, then you need to investigate why that is, or rewrite your code to run under Python 3 instead. Or *test* your code with Python 3 (before freezing) first, your syntax *does not work in Python 3*.

Comment: @Jacobsayshi: When you didn't use VPython you must've run it with Python 2 instead.

Comment: My code is written in Python 3 and works when I run it (as a .py file). Apologies for sounding like a massive noob, I obviously haven't been doing this long enough!

Comment: No, it **cannot** work under Python 3. I demonstrate this in my answer even. Triple-check you are running it with the correct interpreter.

Comment: I couldn't have used python 2 for that one, I've never written in it and don't have it on my pc.

Comment: Let me reiterate one last time: the syntax you are using is invalid in Python 3, it has been since the first Python 3.0 release. Now, I cannot see if this is your own code or a third-party library, as your error message is just a screenshot of a detail of the traceback. It is theoretically possible cx_freeze installed a Python 2 version of a library you depend on, but that is impossible to tell .

Comment: Okay I'll re-install everything and look into it, thanks for the help, sorry to have been such a pain!

Comment: A closer look shows it is the [TTX/FontTools project](http://sourceforge.net/projects/fonttools/) that is throwing that error. Version 2.4, as downloaded from SourceForge, is *not* Python 3 compatible. I see VPython includes it, perhaps they created a Python 3 compatible fork of that library, and cx_freeze is ignoring that and grabbing a new copy for you. I'm sorry, I don't know enough about cx_freeze to help out with that part.